# Isomorphism type of first fundamental groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, fundamental-groups

Given a topological space $X$ and a point $b$ of it, what does "*the isomorphism type of all $\pi_1(X,b)$*" which is denoted by $\pi_1(X)$ mean? After that, I want to understand what does it mean to have trivial $\pi_1(X)$.

Do we classify fundamental groups based at different points of the space up to isomorphisms, somehow?

Comment: If you choose a different basepoint, the fundamental groups are technically not the same.  But, if two different points are in the same path component, the fundamental groups will be isomorphic via a canonical isomorphism generated by any path connecting them.  A trivial fundamental group means that all loops at the basepoint can be contracted.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 The isomorphism is not canonical; it depends on the path you consider joining the two basepoints.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I meant canonical once a path is chosen.  I can see now that my phrasing is wrong and misleading.

Comment: I intuitively know what contraction is, so, can you please explain it in a simpler way if it is possible?

Comment: That is why one defines fundamental groupoid instead of fundamental group https://mathoverflow.net/questions/175923/why-are-we-interested-in-the-fundamental-groupoid-of-a-space